# Use of HTTP functions in GCP Cloud Functions Is Not Secure. Why they are still available?

Tags: http, google, cloud-computing

As Google mentions itself in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule),

> the HTTP functions in Cloud Functions have no authentication and are not secure. HTTP functions are unprotected and will respond to any HTTP request, which means anybody on the internet could start and stop your Compute Engine instances.

What is the real use of such HTTP functions then? Why they are available at all?

Comment: The same page says, _"You may want to simplify this architecture by using Cloud Functions HTTP Triggers"_. This is not really a question related to information security anyway.

Comment: @multithr3at3d then what is infosec if not understand ing and eliminating root causes of vulnerabilities? What is infosec if not caring about solution security and architecture? Anyway I would like to understand why this HTTP is enabled and when it is reasonable to use that insecure solution in practice. Solution simplification does not really answers this in the context of cloud security.

Comment: it looks like you can secure it with your own authentication. Also, HTTPS can be used. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46358013

Comment: Why is some simple, convenient, and insecure thing available? The answer is always: "Because it is simple and convenient, and many people do not value security until they learn the hard way."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because the HTTP functions were the original functionality, and predate the secure Pub/Sub replacement methods.

There are also indirect signs of [a deprecation roadmap for some subfeatures](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation):

> Note: The default behavior for HTTP functions will change after January 15, 2020. Currently, new HTTP functions allow unauthenticated invocation by default. New HTTP functions created after January 15, 2020 will require authentication by default. You can specify whether a function allows unauthenticated invocation at or after deployment.